# Call a phone number with android without leaving app

Tags: java, android, phone-call

I have an app that, due to lack of mobile data in all areas, uses phone connection to make a phone call. There is some important information on the screen in my app, so I want to place the call without leaving my app screen. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permission in mainfest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Use the below code to start calling

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456789" ));
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to implement inside tha app read the [tutorial](http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2009/01/my-own-phone-dialler-only-on-android/) which will help you alot

Comment: The OP states that they "want to place the call without leaving [their] app screen." I believe this means that they don't want to see the call-in-progress screen, in which case, this won't do it.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, Yeah, that's the problem. I do know how to create intent, even dialer, not really the issue. Trying to find workaround to not have to leave my original app. (Pressing back is out of the question because it acts in too many different ways, depending on phone. Even recents may or may not app if intent was initiated from original app, depending on android version)

Comment: @troph AFAIK, this isn't possible. Maybe on a rooted phone, or a custom ROM, but I don't know that for certain.

Comment: @troph follow the tutorial which i provided the link it will definitely help you

Comment: @YounasBangash, implementing the code in the tutorial leaves the app, and asks to make phone call with "phone" app or skype or hangouts. Not what I am looking for.